# How change the size of sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios, box2d, objective-c

I want to change the scale of sprite like a paper in 'Paper Toss' game.

'Paper Toss' is the game is available on the App store. I want to make a sprite like a paper and change the scale of sprite like a paper in 'paper Toss'.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the size of a sprite like so:

```
[mySprite setScaleX: newWidth/mySprite.contentSize.width];
[mySprite setScaleY: newHeight/mySprite.contentSize.height];
```